# Regular Expression (Languages)

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Let L be the language given by $\{w ∈ \{a,b\}^∗||w|_b \;is \;even \;and\; w\; does \;not \;end \;with \;b\}$.

Give a regular expression for the language $L$ and explain your answer.

At the moment i came up with this:

$L(a^*(a^*((ba^* ba^*)^*a) ^* ) ^*a ^*)$

But isnt this an overkill? The $(ba^* ba^*)^*$ makes sure the arbitrary number of $b$'s stays even. So if this is zero times repeated then there will be zero $b$'s. This is ok since $0$ is even. The $a$ after this sentence $(ba^* ba^*)^*a$ makes sure the word doesn't end with an $b$. But i am not sure this is correct or did i used to much? Is the empty word als possible?

Yours sincerely,
Thijs

Comment: Or should it be L(A* ((BA* BA*)*A)*A*) ?

Comment: Your answers are correct but they are indeed overkill. Try to avoid nesting Kleene stars as much as possible. Just think about what you really need. With $(ba^*ba^*)^*$ you recognized the most important bit. Also you added $a^*$ in the front to make sure words can start with $a$ and $a$ at the end to make sure words don't end with $b$. This gives $r=a^*(ba^*ba^*)^*a$. Lastly, $\varepsilon$ should be in this language, but for the empty word I find it ok to add it seperately. So we end up with $L=L(\varepsilon |a^*(ba^*ba^*)^*a)$

Comment: I also want to note that there are shorter solutions, e.g. $L(((ba^*ba^*)^*a)^*)$ but I find those are not readable that well and readability should be an important aspect imo. You want someone to understand what you did there, so keep it as intuitive as you can.

Comment: And what about a's afterwarts ? Now we end with an a but we are not able to add multiple a's at the end? And i dont see how the empty word fits in your solution since the explicit a in the end is always there right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can add an arbitrary number of $a$'s after the last $b$ because of the last $a^*$ in $ba^*ba^*$